# Variance associated with factors in GLS (nlme)

Tags: r, anova, variance, generalized-least-squares

First time posting here, so thank you ahead of time for your help.  I'd like to estimate the variances associated with two factors in a relatively simple, but unbalanced GLS model, and I am unsure how to extract that information (or how to manually calculate it).  For the two factors I'm using, DS3 and DS4, DS3 has four levels (WW - ZZ) and DS4 has seven levels (AA - GG).  I've been using the nlme package; the model itself and model output are below.

```
> library(nlme)
> temp_gls4 = gls(output~DS3+DS4,data=temp_month,weights=varIdent(form=~1|DS4))
> summary(temp_gls4)
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: output ~ DS3 + DS4 
  Data: temp_month 
     AIC      BIC    logLik
1199.769 1268.615 -582.8845

Variance function:
Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
Formula: ~1 | DS4 
Parameter estimates:
       AA        BB        CC        DD        EE        FF        GG 
1.0000000 1.2900663 1.1351448 0.9501666 0.7463385 0.8933227 0.9123444 

Coefficients:
                Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  3.853300 0.1232730 31.258279  0.0000
DS3XX       -0.053908 0.1505280 -0.358129  0.7204
DS3YY       -0.119480 0.1505280 -0.793737  0.4278
DS3ZZ       -0.146255 0.1552625 -0.941988  0.3467
DS4BB        0.934175 0.2081654  4.487655  0.0000
DS4CC       -0.093199 0.1098115 -0.848717  0.3965
DS4DD        0.831305 0.2011411  4.132945  0.0000
DS4EE        1.867642 0.2538358  7.357675  0.0000
DS4FF        1.429805 0.1680183  8.509820  0.0000
DS4GG        0.050992 0.1779757  0.286510  0.7746
```

I know that in a traditional balanced least squared situation you can pretty easily calculate the variance of DS3 and DS4 by manipulating the mean squares (e.g. var(DS3)=(MS(DS3)-MSE)/7), but the data here aren't balanced and I don't know the math behind the GLS model and REML as compared to an traditional least squared model.  I've tried using the anova command, but it just produces the F statistics associated with each factor.  Any help you can provide would be appreciated!

Jon

Comment: What do you mean by "the variance of a factor" ? Are you talking about sum of squares as in classical least-squares ANOVA ? Maybe it would be more clear if you tell the goal of your problem too.

Comment: In terms of the problem itself, I'm trying to understand how climate and hydrology (DS3 and DS4) affect steam flows.  Like with a traditional ANOVA, I'm interested in comparing the effects of each factor on stream flow (is the factor important in our systems, followed by multiple comparisons), but I'd also like to be able to quantify the relative contribution of each factor on determining the the value of stream flow in a more general sense (which is the dominant factor).  I thought I might be able to look at the variance of each factor as a relative measure of strength.  Thanks again!

Comment: I've always just called them variance components, but I've calculated them from the mean squares (MS=SS/df) in the past. In this case, under a balanced least squares design, I would have MS(DS3)=var(e)+7*var(DS3), MS(DS4)=var(e)+4*var(DS4), and MSE=var(e), and would use those expected mean squares to solve for var(DS3) and var(DS4).  Thanks for your quick reply, Stephane!